# Compare and obtain strings that differ between two objects in R

Tags: r, string, compare, string-comparison

I would like to compare two objects with 5 strings each in R. For simplicity, we can consider an old rank and a new rank. The input would be:

```
new <- c("XX1","XX2", "XX3", "XX4", "XX4")
old <- c("XX1","XX5", "XX6", "XX3", "XX4")
```

And this would be the expected output:

```
Keep <- c("XX1", "XX3", "XX4")
Get <- c("XX2", "XX4")
Rid <- c("XX5", "XX6")
```

For clarity, the "XX1", "XX3" and "XX4" are kept in the new rank. However, the "XX4" now appears two times and pop along "XX2" in the `Get` object. `Rid` is what is not in the new rank but is in the old one.

I could extract the `Rid` using:

```
library(Hmisc)
Rid <- old[old%nin%new]
```

However, when the string appears more than one time like "XX4" here I find difficult to extract (i.e. `Get`). I would be glad for any suggestions.

Comment: And `Get <- c(setdiff(new, old), new[duplicated(new)])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions of the package `vecsets` could be used

```
#Keep
vecsets::vintersect(new, old)
#[1] "XX1" "XX3" "XX4"

#Get
vecsets::vsetdiff(new, old)
#[1] "XX2" "XX4"

#Rid
vecsets::vsetdiff(old, new)
#[1] "XX5" "XX6"
```